# Word for people of all nationalities that have African ancestry other than "black"

Tags: adjectives, political-correctness

What's a politically correct word that includes all people of *sub-Saharan* African descent no matter what their nationality is? "Black" is not politically correct enough. But "African American" doesn't include non-Americans. And "African" doesn't sound right when describing an African American person (it might be a bit offensive). Is there a synonym for "black" that is inclusive and P.C?

Comment: Is this intended to exclude Morrocans and such?

Comment: How about "Of African origin" or "Of African descent"?

Comment: Why is “Black” not good enough?  Even the Pew Research Center uses it.

Comment: If you are talking about South Africans, in Britain we usually just call them that - adding "black", "white", "Indian", etc, if it is relevant, and not already clear from the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Black" is the correct term. "Afro-American" is a subgroup of "Black", just as "Kikuyu" and "Luo" are.

In the RSA the offensive term "Kaffir" was used during the apartheid years. Now the term "Black" is used; even the great leader Nelson Mandela said "Black".

Respected Medical publications use the term "Black", see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3986110